# Difference between a knight and a meeple

Tags: carcassonne

What is the difference between a knight and a meeple in carcassonne? What about the big Meeple? Can he count as a knight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meeples are any of the roles in the game. Knight, thief, farmer or monk. The big one counts as two.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. But two questions to clarify: 1) is the wagon a meeple (it can fill almost all roles); 2) Do you have a link where this is clearly explained? In the rules we have here, this is not so clearly described...

Comment: This seems to be explained here (French): https://lecoindujeu.com/jeu-de-societe/carcassonne/

Answer (score 4):

A meeple is a humanoid-shaped physical object.

> You will find in the box 40 regular meeples, including 8 meeples in each of these colors: yellow, red, green, blue, and black.

[image: Meeples]

They were called "followers" in earlier versions of the game/rules.

---

"Knight" is one of the roles the meeple can occupy. A meeple in a city is called a knight.

> Placing a meeple as a knight
>
> Then, you see if there is already a meeple as a knight in the city. Here, there isn’t, so you can place one of your meeples as a knight in this city.

Other roles include highwayman (on a road), monk (in a monastary) and farmer (in a field).